# Can I install and use multiple mods at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

If I have mods, can I use them at the same time or keep shifting between mods? For example Too many items mod and single player commands. I do know you need mod loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use them at the same time, unless they overwrite the same class files in the Minecraft jar, or try to register new blocks with identical Block IDs. TMI and SPC shouldn't conflict like that.